# spring function in aws lambda not sending back status code

Tags: spring, aws-lambda, spring-cloud-function

I had the following code working and returning a statusCode.

```
        final APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent responseEvent = new APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent();
        responseEvent.setHeaders(Map.of(CONTENT_TYPE, APPLICATION_JSON));
        responseEvent.setBody(objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(response));
        responseEvent.setStatusCode(200);
```

However i have recently updated the spring function adapter to 3.2.3, and i no longer recieve the status code in the response. In fact the response is now just the body.

My setup is aws lambda using spring function, behind api gateway.

Answer (score 0):

this works.

```
final APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent responseEvent = new APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent();
        final Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<>();
        headers.put(CONTENT_TYPE, APPLICATION_JSON);
        final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
  responseEvent.setBody(objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(response));
            responseEvent.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.OK.value());
        Message<APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent> finalResponse = new GenericMessage<>(responseEvent, headers);
```